# JavaScript Closures and parent parameters

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following code which is a little bit messy but I would like to understand two points -

f and g are both inner function(a,b) which remember the hello(c,b) parameters    from the time they were created.

1. Let say I call g with some parameter - and then change his parent parameters , do I also change f parent parameters? of that f and g have separated stack framework?
2. when I call hello.change("a") - how can I know what's his the parent parameters x and c? are f or g effect the change function?

```js
 x = "unimaginably";
 var c = "inconceivably";
 
function hello(c,b) {
 var x = 30;
 b.change = function (d){
  console.log("d is =" + d);
  c=d;
  console.log("x is =" + x);
  return this.x;
 }
 return function (a,b) {
  //x is the varible in the wrap function
  console.log("x= " + x);
  if(x == undefined) {x = a}
  else if (b != undefined) {x = b}
  else if (c != undefined) {x = c}
  return x;
 }
}
f = hello("impossible" , hello);
g = hello("impossible" , hello);
f.x = "mistake";
g.x = "error";
hello.x = "arguably"; 
x = f("no","yes");
x = g( "maybe" , "possibly");
x = hello.change("undoutly");
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing variables with properties. `x` is a variable that can only be accessed inside the scope of `hello`. It can neither be accessed via `this.x` nor via `f.x`,`g.x` or `hello.x`.

Comment: I got the idea , see my following question to @Bergi.

Answer (score 0):

> Let say I call g with some parameter - and then change his parent parameters, do I also change f parent parameters? of that f and g have separated stack framework?

No. The closure scopes of `f` and `g` are different, because they were created in different calls to `hello` (each of which created its own `c`, `b`, `x` variable set).

> when I call hello.change("a") - how can I know what's his the parent parameters x and c? are f or g effect the change function?

In your case `g`, because that's the last function whose creation `hello` call wrote to `hello.change`.

Comment: Great , but still don't fully understand the connection between  `g ` and `hello.change` can you please explain more about this?

Comment: They are both references to functions that were created in the same `hello` call (namely `g = hello("impossible" , hello);`) and therefore share the same set of `c`, `b`, `x` variables that they can access via closure.

Comment: O-K , i got the idea , thank you and have a nice day.